# Windows 7 remote user and local user at once

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote

Can I remote into Windows 7 as one user, while another user is logged in at the computer as a different user - and have both be able to do stuff at once?

Answer (score 6):

No.  Windows 7 is a consumer OS and does not support simultaneous sessions.  You'd need a server OS for that.

Answer (score 1):

There exist [a few unofficial patches](http://www.google.com/search?q=windows+7+terminal+services+concurrent+patch) for enabling concurrent sessions on Windows 7. However, be *very careful* when using them.